# how to check if selected file type with FileReader

Tags: javascript, filereader

Below is my code to preview a file. the if statement always returns false. so the code inside never gets run. when I log out a file it returns type: `image/png` but it does not accept this when comparing in the if statement

```
let fileInput = document.getElementById('files')
let filesContainer = document.getElementById('files-container')
let numberOfFiles = document.getElementById('number-of-files')
function preview() {
  filesContainer.innerHTML = ''
  numberOfFiles.textContent = `${fileInput.files.length} Files Selected`

  for (i of fileInput.files) {
    let reader = new FileReader()
    let figure = document.createElement('figure')
    let figCap = document.createElement('figcaption')
    figCap.innerText = i.name

    console.log(i)

    figure.appendChild(figCap)
    reader.onload = () => {
      if (i.type.match('image/png')) {
        consel.log('PNG')
        let img = document.createElement('img')
        img.src = reader.result
        figure.appendChild(img)
      }

      /*
                        if (i.type == "image/jpeg" || i.type == "image/png" || i.type == "image/gif") {
                            console.log("Hello?");
                            let file = document.createElement('img');
                            file.setAttribute('src', reader.result);
                            figure.insertBefore(file, figCap);
                        } else if (i.type == "model/stl") {
                            console.log(`${i.name} is of type stl`, i);
                        } else {
                            log(`${i.name} is of type ${i.type} and is not supported`);
                        }*/
    }
    filesContainer.appendChild(figure)
    reader.readAsDataURL(i)
  }
}
```

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: `i.type.match('image/png')`, this must be invalid, the argument for `match` should be a regexp, maybe you just wanted to compare using `===`?

Comment: @JakubKotrs Nope i just real quick tested of it works but the if statement still did not returned true

Comment: I just tried your code,  selected a png image, and it worked without errors. Frankly, I think the problem is the typo in the console.log statement as that is the only thing I changed. And that would prevent it from working.

Comment: @Yogi Hmm strange i added the log after is was not working but it was in the DOM now i fixed the typo and it works...

Comment: I posted your code to an answer.  It works for me with Edge.  Give it a try.

Comment: Also, using string.match() is fine.  It automatically converts the text to regex for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i Found out why it was doing so strange i had an file in my test collection that made the reader never finish so it never got the the part of if statement the fix i used is adding the reader.onload inside the if statement like this

```
if (i.type.match('image/png')) {
   reader.onload = () => {
   let img = document.createElement('img')
   img.src = reader.result
   figure.appendChild(img)
   }
}
```